# Sorting A Nested Object By Property Not Working

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm trying to sort an object, `players` by the `average` property of the instances of `player` within it, but I can't access make it work.

This is what the Players object looks like when I log it:

```
[ Player { player_id: 1, scores: [ 50 ], total: 50, average: 50 },
  Player { player_id: 2, scores: [ 80, 70, 60 ], total: 210, average: 80 },
  Player { player_id: 3, scores: [ 90, 85 ], total: 175, average: 90 } ]
```

But my sort function seems to fall flat - I think I need to add `player` somewhere to access the nested objects.

Here's that function code:

```
/* class definition excluded */

    top = (num_players) => 
      Object.values(this.players)
        .sort((a, b) => (a.average - b.average))
        .slice(0, num_players);
};
```

The test that's written for this function returns the following:

```
Top 3 [[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]] should equal [3, 2, 1]:
```

For context, here's the entire script with test cases, in case you'd like to try it out:

```js
class Player {
  constructor(player_id, score) {
    this.player_id = player_id;
    this.scores = [score];
    this.total = score;
    this.average = this.averageScore();
  }

  addScore(score) {
    this.total += score;
    this.scores.push(score);
    return score;
  }

  averageScore() {
    return this.scores.length ? this.total / this.scores.length : 0;
  }

  resetScore() {
    this.scores = [];
    this.score = 0;
  }

};

class LeaderBoard {

  constructor() {
    this.players = {};
  }

  add_score(player_id, score) {
    if (!this.players[player_id]) {
      this.players[player_id] = new Player(player_id, score);
    } else {
      this.players[player_id].addScore(score);
    }
    var average = this.players[player_id].averageScore();
    return average.toFixed(1);
  }

  top = (num_players) =>
    // console.log(Object.values(this.players);
    Object.values(this.players)
    .sort((a, b) => (a.average - b.average))
    .slice(0, num_players);

  reset = (player_id) => {
    this.players[player_id].resetScore();
  }
};

// Test code here

function array_equals(a, b) {
  if (a === b) return true;
  if (a == null || b == null) return false;
  if (a.length != b.length) return false;
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    if (a[i] !== b[i]) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

var leader_board = new LeaderBoard()

leader_board.add_score(1, 50)
console.log(leader_board.add_score(2, 80) == 80)
console.log(leader_board.add_score(2, 70) == 75)
console.log(leader_board.add_score(2, 60) == 70)
console.log('Add score should return the average. test with 1 score')
console.log(leader_board.add_score(3, 90) == 90)
console.log('Add score should return the average. test with 2 scores')
console.log(leader_board.add_score(3, 85) == 87.5)
console.log('Top 3 [' + leader_board.top(3) + '] should equal [3, 2, 1]:')
console.log(array_equals(leader_board.top(3), [3, 2, 1]))
console.log('Top 2 [' + leader_board.top(2) + '] should equal [3, 2]:')
console.log(array_equals(leader_board.top(2), [3, 2]))
leader_board.reset(3)
console.log('After reset top 3 [' + leader_board.top(3) + '] should equal [2, 1, 3]')
console.log(array_equals(leader_board.top(3), [2, 1, 3]))
```

I'm expected that `top` will be able to sort the object of `players` by their `average`, then return them in an array from `0 to num_players` but I'm not sorting successfully.

I haven't had any luck so far - How do I sort by the nested property?

Comment: What's the result you're currently getting?

Comment: Top 3 [[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]] should equal [3, 2, 1]:

Comment: `leader_board.top` returns an array of `Player`s; your test expects an array of `player_id`s. Which is correct?

Comment: You see `[object Object]` when you use an object where a string is required. The problem isn't with sorting, it's with what you do with the result.

Comment: @Barmar what should I be doing with the object then?

Comment: It's happening because you're concatenating the array of objects with a string.

Comment: Change `leader_board.top(3)` in your `console.log` calls to `leader_board.top(3).map(l => l.player_id)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You're comparing the `Player` objects to the property of the object itself (`player_id`).
   A correct assert statement will look something like this:

```
console.log(array_equals(leader_board.top(3).map(p => p.player_id), [3, 2, 1]))
```

2. You're sort function is in the wrong direction, simply switch it to be:

```
    sort((a, b) => (b.average - a.average))
```